# Why am I not gaining XP in Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

I recently completed True Vault Hunter Mode by myself as Zero and it came up with Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode. It said I could level up to 61 but I've been playing for a good hour now and nothing has happened - no XP at all? I'm level 50 btw

Comment: Stupid question: Are you actually sure that you selected UHVM?

Comment: There is sometimes a situation when some DLC does not install properly - remedied by toggling things in in-game DLC menu or verifying game integrity in Steam. But yes, first of all go to character selection, re-select your character and make sure you choose UVHM.